# Ruby on Rails: Default will_paginate to last page of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate

Is there an easy way, to default will_paginate to last page? I would like to show user latest addition and allow to browse previuos pages of results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution was the most resonable idea I found:

http://groups.google.com/group/will_paginate/browse_thread/thread/63b8d295f25085c2

Answer (score 1):

Just order your query so that it's in reverse chronological order.

```
Post.paginate(:page => (params[:page] || 1), :per_page => 20 :order => "created_at desc")
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is to reverse the sorting order, i.e. add

```
    :order => 'created_at DESC'
```

to your paginate call. User would expect the "latest addition" on the beginning, and older ones on the following pages.

Comment: It's not the solution. I need the chronological order, but I need to point user to the last page.

Comment: I wish I could take back my downvote but it's too late. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25529043/761771