# Getting will_paginate to reverse the per-page order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I'm trying to get will_paginate to order my posts so that the newest post appears at the top of the first page but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to do that.

This is the order when I sorty by `...order(:published_at)`

Page 1

```
2014-08-05
2014-08-04
2014-08-03
2014-08-02
2014-08-01 <- Oldest post
```

Page 2

```
2014-08-10 <- Newest post
2014-08-09
2014-08-08
2014-08-07
2014-08-06
```

And this is what it does when I `...order("published_at DESC")` it

Page 1

```
2014-08-06
2014-08-07
2014-08-08
2014-08-09
2014-08-10 <- Newest post
```

Page 2

```
2014-08-01 <- Oldest post
2014-08-02
2014-08-03
2014-08-04
2014-08-05
```

But this is the order I actually want:

Page 1

```
2014-08-10 <- Newest post
2014-08-09
2014-08-08
2014-08-07
2014-08-06
```

Page 2

```
2014-08-05
2014-08-04
2014-08-03
2014-08-02
2014-08-01 <- Oldest post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in my case, I am my own worst enemy.

This was my code in `index.html.erb`

```
<% @blog_posts.reverse.each do |blog_post| %>
  #            ^^^^^^^
  <%= render "blog_post", blog_post: blog_post %>
<% end %>
```

and this should be the code in my `index.html.erb`

```
<% @blog_posts.each do |blog_post| %>
  <%= render "blog_post", blog_post: blog_post %>
<% end %>
```

and in my controller

```
def index
  @blog_posts = BlogPost.
    published.
    page(params[:page]).
    order("published_at DESC")
end
```

Produces this order

Page 1

```
2014-08-10 <- Newest post
2014-08-09
2014-08-08
2014-08-07
2014-08-06
```

Page 2

```
2014-08-05
2014-08-04
2014-08-03
2014-08-02
2014-08-01 <- Oldest post
```